# Restkit 0.2 postObject always returns request.body=(null)

Tags: ios, restkit

I am banging my head with restkit 0.2 and posting objects. I am trying to post an object with mapped requestDescriptor but always get a request.body=(null) in my request. I am currently totally stuck.

I am using the following code for mapping

```
// Construct a request mapping for our class
RKObjectMapping *requestMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[requestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
 @"command": @"requestedCommand" ,
 @"payload": @"payloadForCommand"
 }];
RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:requestMapping objectClass:[ShoppingListAPI class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[manager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];

// create the object
ShoppingListAPI *shoppingListRequest = [[ShoppingListAPI alloc] init];
shoppingListRequest.payload = payload;
shoppingListRequest.command = @"getShoppingLists";
```

and try to post it with

```
[manager postObject:shoppingListRequest
                                path:@"shoppinglistWebservice.html"
                                parameters:nil
                                 success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *result) {
                                            DLog(@"We object mapped the response with the following result: %@", result);
                                    }
                                failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                        DLog(@"Hit error: %@", error);

                                }];
```

From the logs I get the following

```
T restkit.network:RKHTTPRequestOperation.m:150 POST 'http://www.myhost.com/shoppinglistWebservice.html': 
request.headers={
Accept = "application/json";
"Accept-Language" = "de, en, fr, ja, nl, it, es, pt, pt-PT, da, fi, nb, sv, ko, zh-Hans, zh-Hant, ru, pl, tr, uk, ar, hr, cs, el, he, ro, sk, th, id, ms, en-GB, ca, hu, vi, en-us;q=0.8";
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
"User-Agent" = "myapp/1.0 (iPhone Simulator; iOS 6.0; Scale/2.00)";
}
request.body=(null)
```

I followed the example implementation from RKObjectManager.h with no success. request.body stays null. Isn't it supposed to show my object as JSON string? Mapping is working fine, i.e.

```
Mapped attribute value from keyPath 'command' to 'requestedCommand'. Value: getShoppingLists
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The last I checked (last week) the examples and most documentation is still for 0.1 or earlier, thus a world of pain right now. Check [NSScreencast](https://www.nsscreencast.com) for videos of RestKit 0.2.

Comment: Same problem here....I am digging hard....

Answer (score 1):

```
RKRequestDescriptor *reqDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:mapping objectClass:objectClass rootKeyPath:path];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:reqDescriptor];
```

For mapping use `[mapping inverseMapping]`

For objectClass `[Someclass class]`. Path can be nil mostly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you managed to solve this, but I finally worked out why I was unable to post - it was very frustrating:

I needed to add this:

```
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType=RKMIMETypeJSON;
```

to get the request to post as JSON.

Problem solved from that point on.
Can't work out why this isn't a more widespread answer